# High CPU usage while playing a YouTube video

Tags: linux-mint, cpu, video, browser

I have installed `Linux Mint 18.2 Cinnamon (kernel: 4.10.0-32-generic)` on my new `ASUS UX430UA notebook`. It has `Intel Core i5-7200U`, integrated graphics only - `Intel HD Graphics 620` and 8 GB of operating memory.

I noticed that when I'm playing YouTube video, even when it is minimized, it has high CPU usage - around 40% of each CPU core with 720p@25 video. Compared to my previous notebook - MSI GE60 2OC with Intel Core i5-4200M it is four times more. Intel Core i5-7200U should be even a bit faster (tried benchmarks proven this to me).

**What I tried:**

- different web browser - all have this issue for me
- check CPU throttling
- custom compiled Chromium from public repository with forced HW decoder (also set in chrome://flags) - in chrome://media-internals was written that I am using HW decoder
- install recent intel-microcode
- try different Linux distribution

Is it normal with this configuration (which I don't think) or can you tell me what I am missing?

**EDIT:**

All tested web browsers runs very strange in this issue. When I launch them first time after boot and load page with video from YouTube, CPU usage stays about 40 seconds of video playing at 5% per core. After, it increases to 40% per core. Then even when I launch any others web browser or the same one again, playing video consumes 40% of each core usage. No web browser background processes are running by my research.

**EDIT 2:**

It seems that installing `i965-va-driver` package helps with playing videos with local video players as `xplayer` and more effective with `vlc`. Strange is that my old laptop MSI didn't require installing something like that and plays videos with local video players even a bit more effective (lower CPU usage) - I don't think that in LiveCD OS uses a dedicated GPU (in my case Nvidia GT750M) for HW video decoding. Installing that package also helps a bit with playing videos on YouTube with custom compiled Chromium with forced HW video decoding, but I believe there is still much to improve.

I hope that this all is caused by newer hardware and it will get some support in this area later.

Comment: Which window manager? Does the video has some sound? Do you hear it?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch `wmctrl` shows me `Mutter (Muffin)`, `$XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP` - `X-Cinnamon` and `$DESKTOP_SESSION` - `cinnamon`. Yes, videos that I played has sound and I hear it.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Also I tried it with other distros, which means that this probably isn't window manager problem (Peppermint 8 has Xfce with Xfwm for example). Also I tried it on Asus and previous MSI with the same conditions from LiveCD boot and my new Asus had four time higher CPU usage here as well.

Comment: Do you have Windows on this laptop? Does it have the same problem?

Comment: @MiniMax Firstly I had preinstalled Windows 10, but I have removed it earlier than I could noticed the same behavioral. So I don't know if it had the same problem and if so, what would it mean?

Comment: @NikNovák "what would it mean?" Just additional information. Also, it means that the problem is not Linux specific. Do you notice performance drop in another applications? For example, if you play any video (better the one downloaded from youtube) by `vlc`, does it show such performance difference with the old laptop?

Comment: @MiniMax I tried it before a moment with `xplayer`, because I had the same idea. I tried to run TimeShift video recorded by my Xperia and this video is 720p@120 in MP4 format. CPU usage was below 40% of each CPU core on both machines.

Comment: @NikNovák Now, try open this video by some browsers - the right mouse button click on the file and select "open with Firefox", for example. Does difference appears? If not, you should get H.264 video and repeat testing with it.

Comment: @MiniMax Very good idea - I tried it now and CPU usage is the same with FIrefox as in `xplayer` and `vlc` - below 40%.

Comment: Just now, I clicked right button on the youtube video and select "stats for nerds". It show this: ' Mime Type: video/webm; codecs="vp9" '. It need be testing with this video format and codec. You can download video from youtube by DownloadHelper or similar program. Then play this stored file by browser.

Comment: @MiniMax I tried it and the only difference was that video played on YT was vp9, downloaded one was On2 VP8. Both shares 360p@25 (I can't download 720p) and WEBM format. Also they are the same videos of course. CPU usage was pretty the same on Firefox - around 22% per each core. `vlc` (when Firefox was closed) used 15% of each core, which is also pretty high...

Comment: @NikNovák High CPU usage on both machines or only on the new one?

Comment: @MiniMax This was only the new one. The older one (MSI) runs the 360p@25 video on YT with 5% CPU cores utilization. Downloaded video in Firefox with 9%. And downloaded video with `xplayer` with 7%.

Comment: It seems, that it is related by GPU - [Hardware video acceleration](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Hardware_video_acceleration). And either GeForce better accelerates some codecs or Intel is not accelerates them at all. But there are contradictions: 1) GT 750M seems doesn't work with [VP9](https://developer.nvidia.com/nvidia-video-codec-sdk) and 2) Browsers have hardware acceleration disabled by default. But I don't have another explanation for such behaviour. Also useful information - [FFmpeg / libav](https://developer.nvidia.com/ffmpeg)

Comment: @MiniMax It looks that you are right, but I still can't find how to run HW decoded videos in a web browser effectively - look at my EDIT 2 please.

Comment: You can try this Chrome's extension: [h264ify](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/h264ify/aleakchihdccplidncghkekgioiakgal). It should help, because you have quadruple CPU load only with VP9, not with h.264.

Comment: @MiniMax I tried it sooner, but unfortunately it didn't help.

Comment: Especially for all the developers out there: Don't forget to switch off the network log recorder in the dev tools!

It's easy to forget this after debugging something unrelated and it will have an adverse effect on performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is not in way of video decoding or compatibility with used desktop environment. I found that problem is in CPU governor (I found it from my another [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1250153/linux-mint-every-process-consumes-more-cpu-one-minute-after-boot?noredirect=1#comment1835915_1250153)). Both notebooks ASUS and MSI are using `pstate` to driving CPU frequency scaling. However, frequency on MSI is higher than ASUS in the same circumstances, so CPU usage on ASUS must be higher to product the same processing power (explain original question and EDIT 2). It is probably caused by that MSI has i5-4200M, whereas ASUS has i5-7200U, which should be powersave processor compared to i5-4200M, so it holds frequency as low as possible. Also, I don't know why, but one minute after boot, ASUS holds its CPU frequency on the maximum (explain EDIT comment).

**Solution:**

It really doesn't exist, because it is not problem at all. It is powersafe (but also quite powerful) processor, so power consumption is also important. However, if it is really required to hold this processor on the maximum frequency and see beautiful numbers in CPU usage, it is possible to change CPU governor from `powersave` to `performance` - look on the Internet (but remember that your CPU must be driven by `pstate`).